# If two textbox's value is not blank execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle: http://liveweave.com/TBJ9EZ

I have two textbox's `input[type=text] elements` and what I want to do is as soon as they have a value "not blank" I want to show a div, and once either of them has a blank value to hide the div.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var AppName = $(".appname").val(),
      AppUrl = $(".appurl").val();

  $("input").on("keyup change", function() {
    if ((AppName === "") && (AppUrl === "")) {
      $("div").addClass("hide");
    } else {
      $("div").removeClass("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Check Fields</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input class="appname" type="text" placeholder="Application name"> 
    <input class="appurl" type="text" placeholder="http://website.com/">
    <div class="hide">All fields are filled :)</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use move statement to fetch value inside click handler.

```
$("input").on("keyup change", function() {
  var AppName = $(".appname").val(),
      AppUrl = $(".appurl").val();

    if ((AppName === "") && (AppUrl === "")) {
      $("div").addClass("hide");
    } else {
      $("div").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

You can also use [`.toggleClass(state)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-state)

> A boolean value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.

```
$("input").on("keyup change", function() {
    $("div").toggleClass("hide", $(".appname").val() === "" && $(".appurl").val() === "");
});
```

Comment: I have to have the variables in the input function?

Comment: @mikethedj4, I didn't get your comment, Please rephrase it

Comment: Why do the AppName and AppUrl global variables have to be in the input function? And is there a work around? (I'm just trying to understand this better)

Comment: @mikethedj4, value in the `AppName ` is fetched in document-ready then its never updated. You can store reference to element and fetch its value in click handler like http://liveweave.com/PHIWzc

Comment: Now i feel like an idiot lol. I guess that means it's time to refresh my batteries and get some sleep. Mucho gracias amego